# Why "Subjonctif" mode was not used in the following sentence

Tags: conjugaison, subjonctif

While reading a book, I came across this sentence:

> il est possible d'attribuer une probabilité aux différentes valeurs
>   que la variable aléatoire **peut** prendre

Why "peut" is used instead of "puisse"? What I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: "Thiziri": such a nice name ! It means 'star'  in my mother tongue :)

Comment: @Begueradj: Thanks, it's in Chaoui and yoor means "moon".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The indicative is used because there is absolutely no uncertainty about the fact the variable can take the different values referred to.

Should you want to tell taking a value is an hypothesis, you would use the conditional:

> Il est possible d'attribuer une probabilité aux différentes valeurs que la variable aléatoire **pourrait** prendre.

Should there is actually some uncertainty about the fact the variable can take some values at all, you might say:

> Que la variable **puisse** prendre une valeur négative reste à démontrer.

but still:

> Il reste à démontrer que la variable **peut** prendre une valeur négative.

because in that latter case, the demonstration would tell the fact it can or it cannot.

Comment: Also in the syntax, *il est possible **de*** eliminates the need for the subjunctive neatly (cf. *il est possible que*).  The relative clause *que la variable peut prendre* is in the indicative because it refers to the NP different values.